# margin : auto not working vertically?

Tags: css, margin

I try to vertically center a div in an outer div but it doesn't work. I tried to look around on the web but couldn't find an explanation for my specific problem...
When trying to align horizontally it's working => "margin:0 auto;"

Anyone ?

```
<div style="height:240px;width:100%;">

 <div style="width:33%;height:100px;margin:auto 0;">
   <span class="" style="font-size:26px">Hello </span>
   <br/><br/>
   <img style="width:150px" src="example.jpeg"
/>
 </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin:auto` can center vertically [only absolutely positioned elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height) with known height ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bNfa/)):

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin do your work:

```
jQuery.fn.verticalAlign = function ()
{
    return this
            .css("margin-top",($(this).parent().height() - $(this).height())/2 + 'px' )
};
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$("#mydiv").verticalAlign()
```

For your code:

```
<div style="height:240px;width:100%;">

 <div id="mydiv" style="width:33%;height:100px">
   <span class="" style="font-size:26px">Hello </span>
   <br/><br/>
   <img style="width:150px" src="example.jpeg"
/>
 </div>

</div>
```

Just add the following:

```
$("#mydiv").verticalAlign()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table;`

### Markup

```
<div class="outer">

 <div class="inner">
   <span class="" style="font-size:26px">Hello </span>
   <br /><br/>
   <img style="width:150px" src="http://placehold.it/150x50" />
 </div>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
.outer
{
    display:table;
    height:240px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}
.inner
{
    display:table-cell;
    width:33%;
    height:100px;

    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/Nsrv7/)**

Comment: `display: table-cell` for the container is sufficient for centering the content. The wrapper with `display: table` is necessary only if the margin for the container itself is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code. It's Working.....

```
<style>
.child {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border: 1px solid red;
margin: auto auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">
<div class="child"></div>
</body>
```