# Vertical Auto Margin within a Div

Tags: html, css

I'm now trying another strange and not working thing: the **vertical** auto alignment of a child `div`.

I would like the `content` to be vertically centered within the `panel`, because the `panel` have a `height` in % that fits the window size, it's really important for me to have a strict alignment.

All right, here's my code: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fZz3j/)

HTML

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #273034;
    margin: 0;
}

#panel
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 380px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

#content
{
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: rgba(117,169,56,0.9);
}
```

Why a so simple thing doesn't work?

Hope someone could help me, I've tried these solutions: [margin : auto not working vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719198/margin-auto-not-working-vertically) but it actually didn't make the trick

Comment: Ah, yes. One of the many vagaries of HTML/CSS. Horizontal is easy, vertical very problematic. HERE is a very nice discussion - http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for help on formatting your posts. Also, you're not writing an email or a letter, so there is no need for a salutation or a signature.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please add your solution as an answer so others can benefit from it as well.

Comment: Actually what helped me is this discussion:
http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/<br/>
Thanks to TimSPQR!

Comment: If you ever need both vertical and horizontal centering, you may also want to take a look at the [Absolute Centering](http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt) technique.

Comment: O.O
Awesome!
Working too!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple Solution for vertical aligning, using Pure CSS without fixing any top-margin, top-padding. so its totally responcive.

See this <kbd>[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/fZz3j/1/)</kbd>

**HTML:** (Same)

```
<div id="panel">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #273034;
    margin: 0;
}

#panel
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 380px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}

/*this is new*/
#panel:before
{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

#content
{
    vertical-align: middle;     /*this is new*/
    display: inline-block;    /*this is new*/
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;    /*this is new*/
    background-color: rgba(117,169,56,0.9);
}
```

Comment: Very nice one!
I admit that I never heard about ":before" and "content: ''" properties and values, but very cool solution.
Actually you are transforming the elements from block to inline and then you use 'vertical-align: middle' to center it?

Comment: Its a little bit more complicated. I create an empty inline element that takes 100% height of the container, and set his vertical alignment to middle, then make your div `inline-block` and set his vertical alignment to middle. causing him to be centered exactly in the middle of the 100% height.